Count If criteria partial text
How can I count number of cells in a column that contains partial text
I want the result to become 6 since text AB (A and B) can be found from all those rows except Row 4 that has only C in it.


Try: =SUM(N(MMULT(1-ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(B2,SEQUENCE(,LEN(B2)),1),A2:A8)),{1;1})>0)) this will give the exact answer

Or using COUNTIFS() --> =SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)),1)&"*"))

@Harvey do you need it to be case sensitive?

@Mayu the comment transport takes only the first 4 characters of the addressed name.

Is that so. Then you should see others how they are writing

hi @P.b it doesn't have to be case sensitive

This formula returns the count of cells where any character of the FIND criteria is found.
=SUM(BYROW(IF(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2),1),1)),A$2:A$8),0)>0,1,0), LAMBDA(xx,IF(SUM(xx)>0,1,0))))


For fun, expanded and modified the requirement a bit to attempt at a bit more flexible solution.

Utilizing COUNTIF's wildcard (case-insentive) option
Search for phrases instead of just letters
Allow multiple terms separated by a delimiter
Allow input from a range instead of a single cell

Method: collect the terms, wrap in wildcard (*), get the count.



Name
Refers to




_get_pairs_as_col
=LAMBDA(arr, LET( all, arr & TRANSPOSE(arr), TOCOL(_na_if_repeating(all),2) ))


_na_if_repeating
=LAMBDA(text, IF( LEN(SUBSTITUTE(text, LEFT(text,1),"")),  text,NA()))



Main: count_if_partial_ci_match
=LAMBDA(_range,_terms,[_col_delim],[_row_delim],
LET(
_col_delim, IF(ISOMITTED(_col_delim), ",", _col_delim),
_row_delim, IF(ISOMITTED(_row_delim), ";", _row_delim),
_terms, IF(ROWS(_terms)>1, TEXTJOIN(_row_delim,,_terms), _terms),
_all_terms_as_col, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(_terms,_col_delim,_row_delim),2 +N("Ignore errors")),
_count_single, IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIF(_range,"*" & _all_terms_as_col &"*")),0),
_count_pairs, IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIF(_range,"*" & _get_pairs_as_col(_all_terms_as_col ) &"*")), 0),
_count_single - _count_pairs
))


